# Was ist eine formelle, allgemeingültige und nicht-binäre Version von "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren"?

Tags: salutation, gender-neutrality

Ich suche eine generische, allgemein-verständliche bzw. -gültige und formelle Anrede als Ersatz für das in Anschreiben und Briefen verwendete

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,

welche nicht-binäre Geschlechtsidentitäten nicht ausschließt (Stellenausschreibungen zum Beispiel sollen m/w/d oder m/w/x anstatt m/w verwenden um explizit die Existenz nicht-binärer Personen zu verdeutlichen).

Dabei gibt es mehrere Krücken, die versuchen die adressierte Personengruppe in der Anrede direkt [anzusprechen](https://geschicktgendern.de/sehr-geehrte-damen-und-herren/). Z.B.: "Sehr geehrtes Team" / "Sehr geehrte Beschäftigte". Diese sind aber relativ informell oder nicht allgemein gehalten (nicht jede adressierte Personengruppe kann als Team etc. angesprochen werden). Vor allem bei geschäftlichen oder rechtlichen Dokumenten/Briefen wäre es unpassend solch saloppe Formulierungen zu wählen.

Gibt es eine dementsprechende Verallgemeinerung von / Alternative zu "Damen und Herren"?

Answer (score 6):

Einen expliziten Einschluss - nein, keine Kenntnis.

Ich verwende meist so etwas:

> Sehr geehrtes xy-Support-Team,
>
> Sehr geehrte Personalabteilung von Firma xy,

Dabei benutze ich möglichst das, was ich zuvor finde. D.h., gerade bei Hotlines und sonstigen viel-mit-unbekannten-Menschen-in-Kontakt-Tretenden finde ich irgendeine Art von Vorstellungsseite. Und da steht manchmal sowas wie "Ihr XY Support Team".

Das ist m.E. kein expliziter Einschluss nicht-binärer Informationen, sondern nur die Nutzung der Information "sie selbst nennen sich so".

D.h. auch, dass die Addressierung "Personalabteilung" einigermaßen gestelzt klingt, weil ich ja die Leute dort anschreibe und eben *nicht* die Abteilung (als abstrakte Person). Und was ich für Deppenleerzeichen halte etc., das korrigiere ich unaufgefordert.

Randnotiz:

Bei Gruppen, die ich schon kenne, hat sich meist

> Hallo zusammen

eingebürgert.

Answer (score 5):

Jeglicher Ersatz für "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" im Bereich des Höflichen und Förmlichen ist Flickwerk, jedenfalls noch derzeit (im Jahr 2020).

Es gibt verschiedene Versuche mit Partizipien:

- Sehr geehrte Studierende
- Liebe Mitarbeitende

aber sie hören sich immer noch sehr bemüht an.

Im Bereich des Locker-Legeren gibt es Ausdrücke, die sich etabliert haben:

- Liebe alle   (von Englisch *dear all*)
- Guten Tag!  (ohne weitere Anrede)

In rein mündlicher Kommunikation:

- Guten Tag zusammen! (Üblich beim Dazustoßen zu einer lockeren Runde untereinander vertrauter Personen, z.B. im Vereinswesen; klingt jovial)
- Guten Tag allerseits (Wie oben, aber etwas höflicher, also auch möglich zur Verwendung im Kreise Unbekannter)

Answer (score 5):

Auch das umgeht das gestelzt Problem nicht, aber uneingeschränkt generisch wären die folgenden Formulierungen

> Sehr geehrte Menschen (Anmerkung: Habe einen Trans-Freund von mir gefragt und er nannte mir ebenfalls diese Formulierung)
>
> Sehr geehrte Personen
>
> Sehr Geehrte

Oder einfach nur ein

> Guten Tag

Letzteres verwende ich gerne in Emails.

Answer (score 4):

Da m/w/d oder m/w/x in der deutschen Sprache aktuell noch in den "Kinderschuhen" steckt, gibt es hierfür keine generische, allgemein-verständliche bzw. -gültige und formelle Anrede. Ohne die diversen "Krücken" gibt es dafür keine Lösung.

Answer (score 1):

Eine Variante die recht nah am Original ist, ist:

> Sehr geehrte Damen*Herren,

Hier fungiert das Sternchen in der gleichen Weise wie es auch bei anderen Konstrukten eingesetzt wird, wie etwa "Benutzer*in".

Answer (score 1):

Da ohnehin alle "genderneutralen" Formulierungen Neologismen sind, steht es jedem frei, auch für diesen Anwendungsfall eine Neuschöpfung nach Geschmack zu kreieren und zu verwenden. Ob sich eine davon irgendwann durchsetzt und die anderen dann als "falsch" empfunden werden, kann nur die Zukunft erweisen.