# Geschlechtsneutrale formale Anreden

Tags: salutation, gender-neutrality

Ich bin allgemein etwas unglücklich mit den formalen Anreden "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren", "Sehr geehrte Frau X" und "Sehr geehrter Herr X". Meistens ist es in der Kommunikation doch irrelavant, ob der Gesprächspartner männlich oder weiblich ist und sollte deshalb in der Anrede auch nicht vorkommen. Zudem haben diese Anreden das Problem, dass sie Personen, die sich nicht mit einem Geschlecht identifizieren, nicht ansprechen.

Bei "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" möchte man ja eigentlich nicht die Damen und Herren einzeln ansprechen, sondern alle Menschen, die die Mail lesen. "Sehr geehrte Menschen" geht aber wohl nicht in einer formalen Anrede durch, obwohl es vom Abstraktionslevel eigentlich besser ist.

Bei einzelnen Personen, die ich sieze, würde ich wohl am Liebsten "Hallo Vorname Nachname" verwenden, bin mir aber nicht sicher, wie das bei Personen, die ich nicht kenne, ankommt.

EDIT: Noch ein Gedanke dazu: In der Grußformel unterschreibt man in einer formalen Mail ja häufig mit "Vorname Nachname", wieso ist es denn so komisch eine Person so anzureden, wie sie unterschreibt? Es ist doch auch totat komisch mit "Herr X" zu unterschreiben, oder?

Gibt es da bessere Formulierungen?

EDIT: [Was ist eine formelle, allgemeingültige und nicht-binäre Version von "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58678/was-ist-eine-formelle-allgemeing%C3%BCltige-und-nicht-bin%C3%A4re-version-von-sehr-geehr)
hier gibt es Antworten (aber leider keine wirklich zufriedenstellende) auf eine allgemeine Anrede, aber nicht auf persönliche.

Comment: *„[Das Geschlecht] sollte deshalb in der Anrede auch nicht vorkommen.“* Sagt wer? Das sind die häufigsten Anredeformen, also kann das schonmal nicht stimmen. *„Bei einzelnen Personen, die ich sieze, würde ich wohl am Liebsten ‚Hallo Vorname Nachname‘ verwenden, bin mir aber nicht sicher, wie das bei Personen, die ich nicht kenne, ankommt.“* Bei mir nicht gut. Zumindest unterstelle ich dem Absender dann – ob berechtigt oder nicht – zunächst einmal, dass es jemand sei, der sich nicht um Umgangsformen schert.

Comment: Nur weil dass der Standard ist, dass man immer das Geschlecht mit angibt, heißt das noch lange nicht, dass das gut ist. Ich habe ja Gründe angegeben, wieso "Sehr geehrte Menschen" theoretisch besser sein sollte  als "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren".

Comment: Für *sehr geehrte Damen und Herren* siehe diese Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58678/35111

Comment: @Henk, es spielt aber nunmal keine Rolle, was *Sie* als theroretisch besser empfinden. Das heißt nicht, dass Sie nicht schreiben dürfen, wie Sie wollen. Aber dann wird es eben Leute geben (wie mich), die Ihre Variante nicht gut finden.

Comment: Um der Frage einen konkreten Anwendungsfall zu geben: Wie würden Sie denn eine einzelne Person anreden, von der Sie nur Vor- und Nachname  kennen und das Geschlecht nicht wirklich aus dem Vornamen hervorgeht?

Comment: Verstehe ich das richtig -- als Frage bleibt jetzt eigentlich nur noch, wie man einzelne Personen grüßt, deren Geschlechtsidentifikation man entweder nicht kennt oder wo diese "divers" ist?

Comment: Naja, eigentlich möchte ich auch Personen, die sich mit einem Geschlecht identifizieren und ich dieses kenne, nicht mit Geschlecht anreden, wenn das nichts mit dem Anliegen zu tun hat. Man schreibt ja auch nicht die Staatsbürgerschaft oder das Alter dazu.

Comment: Ich habe für Reopen gestimmt, da es in der verlinkten Frage nicht um die Anrede für eine namentlich bekannte Person geht.

Comment: Anreden sind Floskeln, die einem ersparen sollen, nachdenken zu müssen, was und wie jemand angesprochen wird. Wenn Du nicht weißt, ob es eine Frau oder ein Mann ist, frag nach oder schreib "Sehr geehrte Dame/Sehr geehrter Herr".

Comment: "Herr" und "Frau" sind wie das "Sie" ihrem Sinn nach ehrende Anreden, deshalb benutzt man sie nicht in der Unterschrift für sich selbst, und deshalb kann ein Weglassen als Verweigerung der Höflichkeit aufgefasst werden. Es wäre schön, wenn es eine entsprechende ehrende Anrede ohne Nennung des Geschlechts gäbe, aber mir fällt keine ein und ich glaube nicht, dass es eine gibt.